# Let A $\subset C(X)$ is an algebra of continuous functions then prove that the closure of A is also an algebra.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

Let A $\subset C(X)$ is an algebra of continuous functions then prove that the closure of A is also an algebra.

Let's take f, and g in Cl(A)then we need to show f.g and f+g are also in Cl(A).As f is in A there is a sequence fn in A such that fn converges to f in supnorm. similar thing can be done for g. then after I do not know how to proceed.
Any idea?

Comment: If $f_n$ and $g_n$ converge in sup-norm, what can you say about $f_n.g_n$ and $f_n+g_n$? (It's possible that you need $X$ to be compact to make the product work...)

Comment: yea if X is compact then how do we prove?

Comment: You prove that $f_n+g_n$ and $f_n.g_n$ converge in sup-norm. It will take some $\epsilon$-argumentation, proving it directly from the definition of convergence, but it will look more or less like any other such proof you have ever seen and will ever see.

Comment: Thank you. you are right. in case of fn + gn I can do but just wondering about convergence of fn.gn ?

Comment: You would need compactness of $X$ to prove that each $f_n$ and each $g_n$ has a maximum value. From there you can work out how far out in the sequence you need to go for $|f_n.g_n-f.g|$ to be small enough.

Comment: @Arthur, I'm actually working on this problem now myself. And I'm not sure I can work out how far in the sequence I need to go for $|f_{n}g_{n} - fg|$ to be small enough. I was thinking that for $f_{n}$ to converge to $f$ in the sup norm, we'd have $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists N_{1} \in \mathbb{N}$ st $\forall n \geq N_{1}$, $\max_{x \in X}|f-f_{n}| < \epsilon$, which we're guaranteed b/c $X$ and thrfore $C(X)$ is compact. Then, there would be a similar $N_{2}$ for $g_{n}$, and then for $f_{n}g_{n}$, $N = \max \{ N_{1}, N_{2}\}$ or something. Am I on the right track? If not, help please!

Comment: @JessyCat No, it's not quite right. $\max_{x \in X}|f-f_{n}| < \epsilon$ is guaranteed by _convergence of_ $f$, not compactness of $X$. Also, $C(X)$ is _definitely_ not compact just because $X$ is (for instance, $C(\{0\}) \approx \Bbb R$). Also, you're beginning in the wrong end. You need to start with a $\epsilon >0$, and you want to show that there is an $N$ such that for any $n>N$ we have $|f_ng_n-fg|<\epsilon$. Now see that
$$
|f_ng_n-fg| = |f_ng_n - fg_n + fg_n - fg|\\ \leq |f_ng_n - fg_n|+|fg_n-fg|=|f_n-f|\cdot|g_n|+|g_n-g|\cdot|f|
$$and use 1) $X$ is compact 2) $f_n$ and $g_n$ converge.

Comment: @Arthur I assume that your $\lvert\,\cdot\,\rvert$ notation is shorthand for $\max_{x\in X}\lvert\,\cdot\,\rvert$. Then should the last = sign in your comment be a $\le$ sign?

Comment: @user0 Yes, my absolute value signs signify the sup norm here. And yes, I believe you're right about the equality sign.

Answer (score 1):

first of all you should assume that X (domain) is compact. now the rest is not that hard.
let $f_n$ be a sequence converging to f uniformly and also assume that $g_n$ -> $g$ uniformly then:
$$|(f_n + g_n) - (f + g)| <= |f_n - f| + |g_n - g| <= \epsilon$$ for any given $\epsilon$ by definition so $$f_n + g_n -> f+g$$
also $$|f_n.g_n - f.g| = |f_n.g_n - f.g_n + f.g_n - f.g|<= |g_n||f_n-f| + |f||g_n-g| $$
because X is compact then $f , g , f_n , g_n$ are bounded so there exists $M$ such that  $||f|| , ||g|| , ||f_n|| , ||g_n|| <= M$
$$|g_n||f_n-f| + |f||g_n-g| <= |M||f_n - f| + |M||g_n - g|$$
and that completes the proof because $|f_n - f| , |g_n - g|$ can be arbitrarily small

Comment: You should use `\leq` for $\leq$.